# Getting keypress sound file

Tags: audio, keyboard, custom-sounds

How can I go about obtaining the default Android keyboard button press sound file? If it is not readily obtainable, how can I obtain a similar 'click' sound effect?

-Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download them directly from the AOSP source repository:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/data/sounds/effects